# Java Regex Negative Lookahead

Tags: java, regex

After looking through the answers that are already on **StackOverflow** regarding this issue, I settled with the most accurate one I could find:

[Java regex: Negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125459/java-regex-negative-lookahead)

I went over to [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and tested it. I put `/foo/(?!.*\\bbar\\b).+` in the pattern input box and the following in the regex match text area:

> /foo/abc123doremi
>
> /foo/abc123doremi/bar/def456fasola

Gskinner recognised both of these as matches though so clearly either Gskinner is wrong or the regex pattern above isn't correct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `\bbar\b` while your text contains `/bar/`.

What you *meant* is probably `\bbar\b` (i.e. `/foo/(?!.*\bbar\b).+`)

Note that "duplicate the `\`" is *only* required inside of Java String literals. That makes writing regexs in Java a bit of a pain.