# How to find and replace without causing duplication

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a series of text reports with fields like 
`"Contractile Front velocity"`  on them

Some of them have `"Contractile Front velocitycms"` on them instead. There are other terms similar to this where characters like cms have been added.

Each term has a numerical result associated with it and I am trying to put the term and the result into a database. The database field will be (for this example) `"Contractile Front velocitycms"`

So I would like to convert any report (plain text) field that *does not* have cms associated with it, to `Contractile Front velocitycms`.

Because I have a load of find a replace problems to solve I created a method that uses StringUtils.replaceEach so that I can use a simple colon separated text file as a lookup dictionary to do the find and replace.

```
public static String FindNReplace(String n) throws IOException{
    String [] split = null;
    ArrayList<String> orig = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] orig_arr = null;
    ArrayList<String> newDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] newDoc_arr = null;

    String dictionary="/Users/sebastianzeki/Documents/workspace/PhysiologyUpperGITotalExtractorv2/src/Overview/FindNReplaceDictionary.txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictionary));

    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            split=line.split(":");
            System.out.println(split);
            orig.add(split[1]);
            newDoc.add(split[0]);
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

    orig_arr = new String[orig.size()];
    orig_arr = orig.toArray(orig_arr);
    newDoc_arr = new String[newDoc.size()];
    newDoc_arr = newDoc.toArray(newDoc_arr);
    String replacer = StringUtils.replaceEach(n, orig_arr, newDoc_arr);

    return replacer;
}
```

The dictionary looks like this

```
PostPr :Post-Prandial
PostPr :Post-prandial
Nausea :nausea
```

The problem is that if I just use my dictionary to replace `Contractile Front velocity` with `Contractile Front velocitycms` then occasionally, where Contractile Front velocitycms already exists I will get `Contractile Front velocitycmscms`  and the `replaceEach` does not use regex. Can anyone think of a solution to avoid me getting the duplicates mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is *[Negative Lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11125459/17300)* to exclude the trailing part.
Negative lookahead is written as `(?!pattern)` so in your case you want `Contractile Front velocity(?!cms)` as your pattern to match.

You can try this on [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/r4hmca) ...
I used:
    **Regular expression:** Contractile Front velocity(?!cms)
    **Input 1:** This Contractile Front velocitycms already has it.
    **Input 2:** But this Contractile Front velocity does not.

You'll see when you hit the *Test* button that Input 2 gets the "cms" added to it but Input 1 does not get it doubled.